# Adding incremental number at end of every line in text file

Tags: perl, text, sed

I have a text file with URLs in separate lines

```
www.example1.com 
www example2.com
```

I want to add some prefix and suffix to every URLs in text file.

```
gallery-dl -g www.example1.com > link1.txt
gallery-dl -g www.example2.com > link2.txt
```

How I can do this with Perl with command line. I tried with sed but failed. I am on Ubuntu.

I tried this

```
$perl -ne 'chomp;print "gallery-dl -g $_ > link$..txt\n"' urls.txt
```

but `> link1.txt` went into 2nd new line.

Comment: does your file have DOS line endings?

Comment: Why are you doing this?  It seems that you are trying to construct a shell script to perform operations on the urls, but it would probably be better to write a shell script that reads the content of the file and performs those operations rather than dynamically generating the script.  Use the list as input to the script, not as input to a script generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a Windows text file (CRLF-terminated lines) to a unix build of Perl (which expects LF-terminated lines).

Convert your file to a unix file (e.g. using `dos2unix`) or handle CRLF line endings (e.g. by replacing `chomp` with `s/\s+\z//`).